# Predicting the probability of diabetes

Tags: probability, biostatistics

I have collected comments of diabetes patients. In these comments they have also mentioned other symptoms.

Now patients come to my portal to check diabetes possibilities. User enters x,y,z symptoms. I match user entered symptoms matches with how many comments in my database.

Issue is somtimes x,y presents in same comments, some times x present in bunch of comments and y present in other bunch of comments.

How do I calculate the probability I dont understand. Any clue on this?

Comment: You need to tell us how you got your data! Maybe look into logistic regression?

Comment: More information is required. What are your predicting? Type I or Type II diabetes? Based on the description your patients already have the disease. Given that, why wouldn't their probability be 100%. What about other factors, e.g., obesity, diet, etc?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen: Data is comments collected from social media discussion of diabetes patients. Each comments contains symptoms faced by patients. I am not sure logistic regression will help or not.

Comment: @DJohnson: I am predicting do patient have diabetes or not (ignore I, II).Given each comments is considered as 100% diabetes probability. Obesity, diet which ever symtoms patients face, he mention in comment. 
Now when new user comes on my system, he manually insert his symtoms and I want to predict diabetes based on comments data. Any model or logic possible here?

Comment: In your example there are no comments from people without a diagnosis of diabetes, i.e., a *control* group of nondiabetics. Given that fact, probabilistic prediction isn't possible. You need new data that incorporates nondiabetics and includes their symptom-related comments to even begin to figure out how predictive comments are.